# How to print an specific area in windows application form in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I am new to vb.net so I don't know how to print.
I am working on billing application in which a cashier enters details of customer
and then selects items purchased and its price and quantity, these things then added in 'list view'. After this i want that when user clicks a print button,
it should print only specific area which i want to print.
So, how to write a code for that.

Comment: [PrintDocument](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.printing.printdocument) class. Or build a report: [RDLC example - Microsoft Developer Network](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/RDLC-example-dcdfd633/sourcecode?fileId=59924&pathId=1526660731). You should specify the UI framework you're using (WPF, WinForms etc.)

Comment: Tip: Use the "Microsoft XPS Document Writer" printer while testing to save a lot of paper.

Comment: ... or a PDF Printer Driver...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print a specific area like a screenshot here is the code:
Otherwise if want to print specific rows from your listview a give you other code :)

```
Dim WithEvents PrintDocument1 As Printing.PrintDocument = New Printing.PrintDocument


' Add a button on your Form "Button1" named and handle here the click event 
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    PrintDocument1.Print()
End Sub


' Printing process
Private Sub PrintDocument1_PrintPage(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs) Handles PrintDocument1.PrintPage



    Dim x As Single = 10 'e.MarginBounds.Left
    Dim y As Single = 10 'e.MarginBounds.Top

    'put here your width
    Dim mWidth As Integer = Me.Width

    'put here your height
    Dim mHeight As Integer = Me.Height

    ' Create you
    Dim bmp As New Bitmap(mWidth, mHeight)

    ' X cordinate
    Dim fromLeft As Integer = 0

    ' Y cordinate
    Dim fromTop As Integer = 0


    Me.DrawToBitmap(bmp, New Rectangle(fromLeft, fromTop, mWidth, mHeight))

    'Get the A4 size 
    Dim limitX As Integer = e.PageBounds.Width
    'use this to reduce your screenshot for the A4 format page
    Dim reduceMe As Double = limitX / mWidth


    Dim bmoToPrint As New Bitmap(bmp, CInt(mWidth * reduceMe), CInt(mHeight * reduceMe))

    e.Graphics.DrawImage(bmoToPrint, x, y, bmoToPrint.Width, bmoToPrint.Height)


End Sub
```